# SAPUI5 Googlemaps library : multiple markers via list

Tags: google-maps, sapui5

i'm using the SAPUI5 Googlemaps library. It works great for one marker, but i need to add multiple markers based on a list. How can i add all these items to the map ?

```
<Map height="500px" zoom="10" lat="52,03838" lng="5,67866">
<markers>   --> add items="{/GmapMarkers}" ????
<Marker lat="{lat}" lng="{lng}" info="{info}" />
</markers>
</Map>
```

Based on the items in /GmapMarkers i want to fill the map.
Is this possible ?

gr
Hans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use aggregation binding. Here is the example from http://jasper07.secondphase.com.au/openui5-googlemaps/. Look for [Marker cluster](http://jasper07.secondphase.com.au/openui5-googlemaps/samples/markerclustertest.html).

```
    <mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:gmaps="openui5.googlemaps" controllerName="sampleController">
        <gmaps:Map lat="33.408495" lng="-104.521889" width="950px" height="475px" zoom="4" zoomControl="true">
            <gmaps:markerCluster>
                <gmaps:MarkerCluster markers="{/features}">
                    <gmaps:markers>
                        <gmaps:Marker lat="{geometry/coordinates/1}" lng="{geometry/coordinates/0}" info="{properties/city}" icon="http://www.w3schools.com/googleapi/pinkball.png"></gmaps:Marker>
                    </gmaps:markers>
                </gmaps:MarkerCluster>
            </gmaps:markerCluster>
        </gmaps:Map>
    </mvc:View>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Can you mark the answer as correct? :)